# Why does spark-submit fail with "IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource."?

Tags: apache-spark

When I create the jar of my Spark application and try to run it using `spark-submit`, I am getting the following error.

This is the command I used to run.

```
spark-submit --executor-memory 1g --jars s3://test-data-lab-users/spachari/test/test_2.10-1.0.jar
```

This is the error i am getting. Does this mean I have not passed correct parameters in my spark-submit?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr** Remove `--jars` option and start over.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.

You missed your...well...Spark application that the message refers to as *"application resource"*.

That's more obvious when you execute `spark-submit` and see the different command-line options and their meanings.

```
./bin/spark-submit
Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
```

That part `<app jar | python file | R file>` is what you missed.

To reproduce your issue you can simply execute `spark-submit` with `--jars` options without specifying the main jar or class of a Spark application.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --jars target/spark-parent_2.11-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

Quoting `spark-submit --help`, `--jars` is...

> **--jars JARS** Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.

`--jars` can be very helpful when a Spark application depends on additional jar files (aka dependencies), i.e. `mysql-connect.jar` that you cannot (or most likely don't want to) "assembly" to your uber jar.

Comment: I never use `--jars` (I directly specify path to `JAR`), but still one fine day `Spark` started giving me this error. Converting the entire `spark-submit` command into single-line (removing **back-slashes** and **new-lines**) solved the issue. Strange. (`Spark 2.3.0` on `emr-5.13.0`)

Answer (score 4):

`--jars` option is added when you've to supply supporting jars to your application jar.

Application resource missing implies that your main jar is missing as you've passed it with `--jars` option. It's looking for your main jar and since it couldn't find it, it throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because main Jar is missing in spark-submit. Check at `--class` argument. It should be like:

```
--class "your class name with package" "main jar path" "jar parameters"
```