# Spark-submit with properties-file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have tried unsuccessfully to run spark-submit with properties specified in a config file.

I can submit a job using:

```
spark_home/spark-submit \
--class MyClass \
--master spark://my_master \
--files test.config \
--jars build/jars/MyProject.jar, build/jars/Config.jar
```

But when I copy the same to my properties file:

```
spark.class   MyClass
spark.master  spark://my_master
spark.files   test.config
spark.jars    build/jars/MyProject.jar, build/jars/Config.jar
```

On trying to use this file with spark-submit, I get an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource

```
spark_home/spark-submit \
--properties-file  conf/properties.conf
```

Are there any additional arguments I need to provide? I thought I had used the same arguments, but it seems I am still missing a step.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693628/why-does-spark-submit-fail-with-illegalargumentexception-missing-application-r -- it looks like you need to specify your application jar on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark commented, it seems that if you do not specify the --jars and --class option, you must include an argument to spark-submit with your package jar.

You should use:

```
spark_home/spark-submit build/jars/MyProject.jar \
    --properties-file conf/properties.conf
```